# ForeignKey does not save when assigned from get_or_create result

Tags: python, django, django-models

This code will execute fine but the `foreignkey` records won't save in the database:

```
new_org, created = models.Organization.objects.get_or_create(symbol = row['Symbol'], batch=batch_id)
new_org.industry, created = models.DictIndustry.objects.get_or_create(value=row['industry'], batch=batch_id)
new_org.sector, created = models.DictSector.objects.get_or_create(value=row['Sector'], batch=batch_id)
new_org.save()
print(new_org.__dict__)
```

the output has the assigned `industry` and `sector`:

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x1142d0748>, 
'id': 3152, 
'date_created': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 21, 36, 55, 883816, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'date_updated': None,
'generation': 1,
'batch': 0,
'symbol': 'DDD',
'industry': <DictIndustry: Computer Software: Prepackaged Software>,
'sector': <DictSector: Technology>}
```

but the database won't have these records:

```
  id  |         date_created          | date_updated | generation | batch | symbol | industry_id | sector_id 
------+-------------------------------+--------------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------
 3152 | 2019-02-07 16:36:55.883816-05 |              |          1 |     0 | DDD    |             |
```

Both `industry` and `sector` records sink into the database (postgresql) just fine.

I suspect it has something to do with the way I coded the models but I can't spot anything that seems to be spoiling it. Is there anything specific to postgresql that could cause this?

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    generation = models.IntegerField(default=DATA_GENERATION)
    batch = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class AttributeBase(BaseModel):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'value'):
            return self.value
        raise NotImplementedError("value field not implemented for this model and it should have been")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = ('source', 'parent', 'value', 'generation')


class DictBase(BaseModel):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'value'):
            return self.value
        raise NotImplementedError("value field not implemented for this model and it should have been")


class DictSector(DictBase):
    pass


class DictIndustry(DictBase):
    pass


class Organization(BaseModel):
    symbol = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=12, null=False, blank=False)
    sector = models.ForeignKey(DictSector, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(DictIndustry, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with django and django works fine. Just in case it helps someone. If you run django-related code in notebooks, such as Jupyter and alike, don't forget to reload the kernel to pick up changes in the models you are making as you go.

(I tried automatic reloading but it didn't work well for me).